# How to write Python or PHP script to edit this XML file?

Tags: php, python, xml, scripting

I would like to write a script which will edit multiple XML files, I would like to have a script which will do the following;

- Find tag "Preload" delete entire
  tag, find "Preload=?sometext?" and delete.
- Find tag "jumpable" delete    entire
  tag, find "jumpable=?sometext?" and delete.
- Find "tween" and    delete entire tag
- Replace "slide"    with "title", remove this line
- Find "offsety" and    delete entire
  tag
- Find "offsetx"    and delete entire
  tag
- Find    "titleoffsetx" and delete
  entire    tag
- Find "presenter" and delete    entire
  tag
- Find "controls" and    delete entire
  tag
- Find "demooffsetx" and "demooffsety"
  and delete entire tag.
- Replace "flv" with "src", unless it is ".flv"
- Remove type tag, eg. "type=?sometext?"

Before Script:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <presentation>
      <lesson>
        <part src="0301p.flv" breadcrumb="This is example text1">
          <cuepoints>
            <cuepoint time="0:01" preload="priority" tooltip="Demo 3.1(A)" jumpable="yes">
              <tween mode="instant" time="1" />
              <slide flv="demos/0301d1.flv" demooffsetx="-180" demooffsety="60" type="demo"></slide>
              <presenter />
              <controls />
            </cuepoint>
          </cuepoints>
         </part>
       </lesson>
    </presentation>
```

After Script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<presentation>
  <lesson>
    <part src="0301p.flv" breadcrumb="This is example text1">
      <cuepoints>
        <cuepoint time="0:01" tooltip="Demo 3.1(A)">
          <title src="demos/0301d1.flv"></title>
        </cuepoint>
      </cuepoints>
     </part>
   </lesson>
</presentation>
```

Comment: I don't see your "before" part.

Comment: Have you tried? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Stephen Chu, I just edited the question to show "before" part.

Comment: Why do they have to make it so hard, Can't someone give me a example of what to do and I'll do the rest? What is the easiest way to start doing this with beginner programming skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

filename = 'editme.txt' #name of the file you want to edit

def edit(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rU') #reads your file
    text = f.read() #puts everything in file into a string under var text
    f.close() #closes file
    text = re.sub(r'\s[Pp]reload="\w+"', '', text) #delete preload tag
    text = re.sub(r'\s[Jj]umpable="\w+"', '', text) #delete jumpable tag
    text = re.sub(r'<tween.+>\s+', '', text) #delete tween tag
    text = re.sub(r'slide', 'title', text) #replaces slide with title tag
    text = re.sub(r'\s\w+offset\w+=".+"', '', text) #delete offset/type tags
    text = re.sub(r'<presenter.+>\s+', '', text) #deletes presenter tag
    text = re.sub(r'\s+<controls.+>', '', text) #deletes controls tag
    text = re.sub(r'<title flv', '<title src', text) #replaces flv with src in title tag
    f = open(filename, 'w') 
    f.write(text) #replaces all text in file with the edited text
    f.close()

edit(filename)
```

This simple python script should output what you want.

Comment: @Josh - I would not recommend regex like this answer is showing. If I needed to do this, I'd use XSLT. However, if I was going to use Python, I'd use ElementTree.

Comment: @DevNull - How come you don't recommend this way?

Comment: It's too risky. What happens if the word "slide" is used somewhere other than an element name? Or if the attributes aren't in the exact order you're expecting?

Comment: Ah I see. I'm a bit new to Python. How would you use ElementTree to do it?

Comment: I obviously no longer need this script but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Look over PHP's SimpleXML. http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php
Of course, it's not your only option. Just Googling "PHP XML Parser" or "Python XML Parser" will give you a wealth of resources and libraries you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using XQuery to transform your xml data?
XQuery is a language for xml transformation. In my opinion, using an XQuery script would be the best way to solve your problem. [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery)
You'd just need an XQuery engine for executing your script which transforms the input xml into the output (like this one: [MXQuery](http://mxquery.org/))

Comment: No, What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend python based solution with [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). IMHO its the best option since its very rich in functionality allowing XPath, etree or objectify, easy string parsing and tostring conversion, etc.

PHP simply does not provide you with equivalent tool-set.